# Loop inside oracle SP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I need to add Users to Roles.So i have a UserId & Role List.I need to know how can i loop that rolesLst in roles table.
roleLst consist ROLE_ID & ROLE_NAME

### my Code

```
   if (userDTO.uTypes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[]
                     {
                    new OracleParameter("user_id", OracleDbType.Int32, userDTO.userId, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("rolesLst", OracleDbType.Array, userDTO.userTypes, ParameterDirection.Input)
                      };
                        ExecuteNonQuery("sp_AddUserRoles", param);
                    }
```

### Proc

```
 procedure sp_AddUsersToRoles(user_id number, rolesLst T_CHAR_ARRAY)
  as
  begin
    loop
          insert into TBLNEWS_ROLES(USER_ID,ROLE_ID)
          values (user_id,
                 -- HOW TO ADD ROLES ???
                  );
        end loop;
  end sp_AddUsersToRoles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `FORALL` might help. Have a look at the example.

Table:

```
SQL> create table roles (user_id number, role_id varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_roles (user_id in number, rolesLst sys.odcivarchar2list) as
  2  begin
  3    forall i in 1 .. rolesLst.count
  4      insert into roles (user_id, role_id) values (user_id, roleslst(i));
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: I'm calling the procedure from Oracle; you'd do that from your application:

```
SQL> declare
  2    user_id  number := 1;
  3    roles    sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('role1', 'role2');
  4  begin
  5    p_roles(user_id, roles);
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From roles;

   USER_ID ROLE_ID
---------- --------------------
         1 role1
         1 role2

SQL>
```